# Laravel with subdomain losing sessions on redirect

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I use subdomain wildcards to create user specific pages for example {slug}.mysite.com

Users might navigate from mysite.com to {slug}.mysite.com

However I seem to have different login sessions for these two routes / domains.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{slug}.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@showByUsername');

    Route::get('/plans/{plan}', 'PlansController@showslug');

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthControllerClient'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because cookies are specific to subdomain.

This is from config/session.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => null,
```

You will need to set this value to something which will include all of your subdomains.

https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: so i can set 'domain' => 'mysite' if the pattern is always {slug}.mysite.com ?

Comment: Please read that link I gave you, it cites the RFC that details how cookies work. It knows better than I, but I believe the domain would need to be `.mysite.com` -- notice the dot including it's a wildcard.

Comment: if i have .mysite.com would the daulft site (mysite.com) also be included? (without www)